# Difference between read-string and load-string in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have some code which works after replacing read-string with load-string. It is good that the code works, but I would like to know why. What is the difference between the two clojure functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use load-string to sequentially read and evaluate the set of forms contained in the
string

Use read-string to read one object from the string s

(both quoted from [Clojure API](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/api-index.html))

Load-string will evaluate your string as a Clojure expression, and read-string takes the string and returns it as the found data structure, in which case might be an expression.

Protip: `(load-string "(+ 1 2)")` and `(eval (read-string "(+ 1 2)"))` will give you the same result, which is 3

Answer (score 1):

Two notable differences:

`read-string` reads but does not evaluate, while `load-string` reads *and* evaluates.

```
(read-string "(inc 1)") => (inc 1)
(load-string "(inc 1)") => 2
```

`read-string` only reads the first form in the string, while `load-string` loads all the forms in the string.

```
(read-string "1 2") => 1
(load-string "1 2") => 2
```