# Clojure get form from string

Tags: string, forms, macros, clojure

I want to read some code from a file and give this to a macro as a form.
Since I need the form unevaluated I cannot use "load-string".

Is there a possibility to get a form from a string?

e.g the string is "(3 4 +)" and I would like to convert it to prefix notation by a macro of mine. (That is not the real use case here but it is a simple example.)

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554694/difference-between-read-string-and-load-string-in-clojure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at [`read`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/read) and [`read-string`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/read-string). As an example:

```
user=> (read-string "(3 4 +)")
(3 4 +)
```